# Can I update the kernel of my 10.04 LTS to the latest kernel?

Tags: 10.04, kernel

I want to update the kernel version of my current 10.04 LTS to at least 2.6.37 (because the drivers for my eth0 and wlan0 interfaces are included in the said kernel).

If it is possible, how do I do this? Is there a repo I add to my sources list?

Answer (score 10):

You don't have to add the PPA. Just install the linux-image-generic-lts-backport-oneiric package from the lucid-updates suite:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic-lts-backport-oneiric
```

If you're using out-of-tree modules like Virtual Box or proprietary drivers, you'll likely need the headers as well:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic-lts-backport-oneiric
```

Other package names can be found on http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/lucid-updates/linux-meta-lts-backport-oneiric

Comment: thanks, and it will work without any problems? It will not be a problem as there are dependencies, etc.?

Comment: Like the description says: "The quality of these packages is such that you had better know what you're doing. Don't come crying to the kernel team if it kills all of your kittens." It might, it might not, but there aren't any dependency issues.

Answer (score 2):

It is no longer necessary to use a PPA to install 2.6.38 on Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid.

The ubuntu-updates repository for lucid has it now.  You probably already have that in
/etc/apt/sources.list

```
$ apt-cache policy linux-image-2.6.38-12-generic 
linux-image-2.6.38-12-generic:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.6.38-12.51~lucid1
  Version table:
     2.6.38-12.51~lucid1 0
        500 http ://packages/ubuntu-updates/ lucid-updates/main Packages
        500 http ://packages/ubuntu-security/ lucid-security/main Packages

$ sudo apt-get install linux-image-2.6.38-12-generic
```

Note that the "-12" will be incremented for future versions, "-12" is today's version.

To look for future versions:

```
$ apt-cache search linux-image-2.6.38
```

Also ppa:kernel-ppa/ppa has been replaced with ppa:canonical-kernel-team/ppa

See: https://launchpad.net/~canonical-kernel-team/+archive/ppa

Answer (score 0):

I always follow these instructions for Ubuntu/Mint, takes like 5 minutes + download time.
As always be extra cautious when upgrading to a new kernel: it sometimes breaks compatibility with certain software/hardware.
 I never had any issues myself but it goes without saying to practice caution and keep the last working kernel in hand

http://www.unixmen.com/upgrade-your-kernel-the-safe-way-in-ubuntu-linuxmint/