# It is possible to easily upgrade the kernel in 10.04.3 to version 3.0.0 and newer? 

Tags: 10.04, upgrade, kernel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I update the kernel of my 10.04 LTS to the latest kernel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47796/can-i-update-the-kernel-of-my-10-04-lts-to-the-latest-kernel)

It is possible to easily upgrade the kernel in Ubuntu 10.04.3 to version 3.0.0 and newer?