# Installing a new kernel on 10.04 because old kernel can't install my wireless card

Tags: 10.04, kernel, internet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I update the kernel of my 10.04 LTS to the latest kernel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47796/can-i-update-the-kernel-of-my-10-04-lts-to-the-latest-kernel)

Is it possible to install a new kernel to Ubuntu 10.04 using a debian package or something ?

I have a new machine with the Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6230 for Wi-Fi but the kernel won't detect it (maybe because it is newer ?). I don't want to use a newer version of Ubuntu because I much prefer Ubuntu 10.04. I can not connect to the internet by any means on the new machine (not even with a wired Ethernet connection). I need to either have a new kernel or connect to the internet to run an update (which will hopefully solve the problem). I found the driver I need for wifi on [HERE](http://www.intellinuxwireless.org/) but the minmum supported kernel version is (2.6.36).  Any help, please ?

Samir

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked before: [Can I update the kernel of my 10.04 LTS to the latest kernel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47796/can-i-update-the-kernel-of-my-10-04-lts-to-the-latest-kernel)

PS: In case you didn't notice this site has a search feature at the top of the page.

Comment: PLease use the Close button and mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: I don't have enough privileges to do that...