# No network connectivity (not wired or wireless) - RT5390

Tags: 10.04, wireless, asus

I am starting to think I simply need to accept a small loss and sell my new ASUS K73E. Because I really don't enjoy computing when I have to deal with Windough$ and this windows 7 64 bit on my new ASUS is even worse than the old machines with XP.

I have written to ASUS and they simply say "We don't support Linux" and while Ralink's website says they do support Linux I can't get anyone to tell me what model Ralink card might be in my machine.

Is anyone out there who might be able to give me some useful advice????

Here is the answer to command lspci nn && lsusb && lsmod && rfkill list all:

```
di,snd_seq

snd                    54244  16 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm_oss,snd_mixer_oss,snd_pcm,snd_seq_oss,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device

uvcvideo               57374  0 

videodev               34361  1 uvcvideo

v4l1_compat            13251  2 uvcvideo,videodev

soundcore               6620  1 snd

snd_page_alloc          7076  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm

psmouse                63677  0 

serio_raw               3978  0 

lp                      7028  0 

parport                32635  2 ppdev,lp

fbcon                  35102  71 

tileblit                1999  1 fbcon

font                    7557  1 fbcon

bitblit                 4707  1 fbcon

softcursor              1189  1 bitblit

video                  17375  0 

output                  1871  1 video

vga16fb                11385  1 

vgastate                8961  1 vga16fb

ahci                   32360  2 


di,snd_seq

snd                    54244  16 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm_oss,snd_mixer_oss,snd_pcm,snd_seq_oss,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device

uvcvideo               57374  0 

videodev               34361  1 uvcvideo

v4l1_compat            13251  2 uvcvideo,videodev

soundcore               6620  1 snd

snd_page_alloc          7076  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm

psmouse                63677  0 

serio_raw               3978  0 

lp                      7028  0 

parport                32635  2 ppdev,lp

fbcon                  35102  71 

tileblit                1999  1 fbcon

font                    7557  1 fbcon

bitblit                 4707  1 fbcon

softcursor              1189  1 bitblit

video                  17375  0 

output                  1871  1 video

vga16fb                11385  1 

vgastate                8961  1 vga16fb

ahci                   32360  2
```

Edit #2

```
lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 0104 (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 0116 (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cougar Point HECI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation Cougar Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cougar Point High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cougar Point PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cougar Point PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev b5)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cougar Point PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation Cougar Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 1c49 (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Cougar Point 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cougar Point SMBus Controller (rev 05)
02:00.0 Network controller: RaLink Device 5390
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications Device 1083 (rev c0)
```

lsusb

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024  
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:5710 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Thanks for the suggestion because this gave me a model for Ralink RT5390. I have now gone to Ralink.com and downloaded (via Windows 7) the driver package (it is a bz2 file). I hope I can figure out how to install it. And FYI - I was not able to run su (not authorized?) and dmidecode didn't exist (probably needs to be downloaded BUT no internet yet in Ubuntu)

Comment: Please update your question with less information about off topic opinions and more information on your wireless card. If nothing else , identify the card from windows.

Comment: please look at my answer here to see if it helps you with this.  thanks.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/103661/no-internet-10-04/103676#103676

Comment: @iSeth [This](http://askubuntu.com/a/105376/22949) may answer it. I recommend against closing this as too localized.

Answer (score 2):

OK, so now we know it's the ralink 5390, which believe it or not is the same card I have. Follwing a post I made on linuxmint regarding this which can be found [here](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=49&t=73844&sid=f77f15a2c68dca91164c844f58a0ab78#p429927) I will then quote the link in that post which involves getting up and running on 10.10 Maverick which should work fine, I also tested it on 11.04 but nothing older than 10.10.

```
wifi card Ralink 5390 configuration in Ubuntu 10.10 64 bit

by sahab on Dec.18, 2010, under Ubuntu, ubuntu 10.10
Problem:
Got a brand new HP laptop – HP g62x. Installed ubuntu 10.10 and found that I do not     have a wlan interface as one would expect with an active wireless connection.

Thanks to
Great discussion on similar work here @ http://ubuntuforums.org    /showthread.php?t=1600498. Just a different card.`

Solution:
I used the above thread to do my work – banged my head against the wall a couple of     times but it was fun . I am listing down steps that finally worked for me. But     before that, my configurations:

Ubuntu 10.10
64 bit
WPA2 wireless network
OS was freshly installed and there was no specific customization prior to this
RaLink Device 5390. (use lspci to see your model number)

Download the driver from ralinktech.com –> Software –> Linux
Unzip the download zip file anywhere. I did it in the default Downloads directory
cd to the 2010_xxx extracted directory
cd os/linux/
Edit the config.mk file as below:
HAS_ATE=y (no change, it was originally as is)
HAS_WPA_SUPPLICANT=y (no change, it was originally as is)
HAS_NATIVE_WPA_SUPPLICANT_SUPPORT=y (no change, it was originally as is)
HAS_ANTENNA_DIVERSITY_SUPPORT=y originally was n — this was the only thing I modified)
Go back to the 2010_xx directory
run command ‘make’
Make sure ‘make compile’ exists without errors. I got an error “too many arguments to format” towards the end of the compile but it did compile successfully eventually. And so I ignored the errors. You would see ***errors*** if the compile is not successful. In which, something went wrong and you may need to tweak the makefile or config.mk files before compile is successful.
run command ‘make install’ as root. This is not listed in the README_STA_pci file that comes with downloaded driver zip file. This takes of copying the file to /lib/modules/2.6.35-22-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt5390sta.ko. running depmod, creating /etc/Wireless/… folder.
Edit the /etc/modules and add the line at the end of this file
rt5390sta
Edit the file /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf and add the below line to it…
blacklist rt2800pci
Reboot and you should see an ra0 interface when you run the command ‘ifconfig’
You may have to run ‘/etc/init.d/network-manager restart’ command to have it show in the first go.
Once, the wireless icon shows up, look for your wireless SSID and there you go surfing
```

As far as su goes you might want to try `sudo su -l` or just `sudo su`

Answer (score 0):

I would first suggest determining the wifi card in this machine. After a quick google it appears to be an integrated Intel chip. Could you please run and post the results of the follwing commands

```
lspci

lsusb
```

If you have a chance I would also like to know the exact model number of the laptop you have. If you could flip it over and give everything but the serial number that would be helpful. The reason I ask is, the Asus site does not list any type of Ralink driver for this laptop, even for Windows 7.

Comment: Here is the Windows info regarding network adapters  and drivers, I will restart in Ubuntu and run above commands asap:

Comment: Here is the info from Windows regarding network adapters  and drivers, I will restart in Ubuntu and run above commands asap: wireless = 802.11n Wireless LAN card, manufactured by Ralink technology, Driver version 3.1.12.1  - wired = Atheros AR8151 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet controller (NDIS 6.20) Atheros driver version 1.0.0.35  and the info on laptop itself - Model K73E  - Tag on bottom also has K73E - BBR7, Check number = 6831  and ID = 1B and <GA> and 2011-11 along with the 15digit serial number and bar code.

Comment: Can you please check and repost the information from those commands again. I'm not sure how you are copying the info, but the results you have posted look nothing like any lspci or lsusb results I have ever seen. Possibly try `sudo lsusb` or `sudo lspci` even `su -l` and then `lsusb` `lspci`

Comment: I also see you posted this on [ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11691687) as well. Just to verify, could you please run and paste the results of the commands above, by running each command seperatly. I am not aware of what the -nn does, but do not use it please. Also I was curious how it is you are getting the info in Windows 7 as well. Under ubuntu can you also run as su `dmidecode` if you need to install it first `sudo apt install dmidecode` and paste the results to pastebin?

Comment: I got info from windows 7 - CP-Hardware-network-Properties.

Comment: Now I think I have the right driver, however I have been unable to figure out how to get it installed. I have tried using the synaptic package manager with no luck. I have unpacked the bz2  to a tar and unpacked that to a file? Maybe you can help me proceed from here.