# in Ubuntu 10.04 - make your i5 processor run all cores

Tags: cpu

I would like to know if this is possible in Ubuntu 10.04.

I would like to make my i5 processor run all cores at the same level, bringing the first core down, so that the other cores can work also, and not just the first core,  other wise the computer is making the first core run most of the time at full, while the last core doesn't even go up...

Hope you understand. Is there something?

Comment: use command `uname -a`, if any `SMP` shows in the output then your kernel is using what's necessary to use multicore. But again your processor might not exist when the kernel was built. So for better hardware support upgrade ubuntu.

Comment: Wish I Wish done that, I need to run Ubuntu 10.04 for one specific software isn't yet released for ubuntu 12.04

Comment: which specific software? That sounds like your real issue.

Answer (score 2):

Linux automatically tries to spread each process across the available CPU's as long as [Symmetric Multiprocessing](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/SMP-HOWTO.html) is enabled at the kernel level

look in /boot/config-(fill in kernel version here) for the following:

```
CONFIG_SMP=y
```

Then at least at the kernel level, processes are attempted to be distributed evenly.

Unfortunately the situation is slightly more complicated at the user level. Unless a program has [Multithread](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multithreading_%28software%29#Multithreading) support it may only run on one core. Many process intensive programs do have this, but you may need to enable it with a specific option.

For example ffmpeg has the -threads option

Is there a specific processor intensive program you want to be spread out over the cores?

Another thing that may be an issue is the age of the kernel in 10.04 (two years old). With a newer processor, it's possible not all the hooks are in there. You may want to try updating your kernel to the [latest version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47796/can-i-update-the-kernel-of-my-10-04-lts-to-the-latest-kernel) or consider upgrading to a linux distrobution with at 3.0+ version kernel. It looks like there are still [significant revisions to how the linux kernel handles the sandy bridge architecture](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=intel_linux33_drm&num=1).

Comment: Yes, I would like if possible, that all my software that is running to be spread out over. I have 10 users running the computer at the same time, and that is making the first core running high to much as I don't really like, and would like to spread it out....

I will have a look at the latest kernel versions, but I have updated my system to the fullest, as I can't think that Ubuntu 10.04 won't be able to support that i5 3.30GHz processor, as version 10.4 is still LTS and still getting updates....

still looking for a better way to manage it, as I am not sure if updating would just do the job